# program exited with 3221225477

Tags: c

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *processes[4] =
{"ALCapture.exe",
"eausvc.exe",
"GomHelperSvc.exe",
"INAVIUsb.exe"};

int len = 4;

int main() {
    printf ("Checking if processor is available... ");
    if (system(NULL)) {
        puts ("Ok");
    } else {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    char cmd[50];
    char* c;
    int i = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
        c = (char*)(i + 48);
        strcpy(cmd, "Deleting Process... : ");
        strcat(cmd, c);
        strcat(cmd, "0%\n");
        printf(cmd);
        for(int j=0;j<len;j++) {
            strcpy(cmd, "taskkill -im ");
            strcat(cmd, processes[j]);
            strcat(cmd, " -t -f");
            system(cmd);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I tried to run it, it exited with code 3221225477 instead of printing "Checking if processor is available... OK"

Can anyone explain why?

Comment: `(char*)(i + 48)` - `i + 48` is not a pointer. Why would you do that?

Comment: To convert a single digit into a string

Comment: That's not how it's done. But since you're using it to `printf` the result, just use `printf` normally with `%d` instead of building a string.

Comment: I made mistake cause I haven't used c for a long time.

Comment: `3221225477` in hex is `C0000005`

Comment: Did you debug your program? On which line does it fail?